# How can I set my node application out of date for old version?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have 1 node library called `sample`, and anyone who would like to use my library must install it using `npm i sample --save`.

Let say the current version of `sample` is `3.0.0` and I would like to mark the version `< 2.0.0` to be out-of-date.

E.g., client A installs `library@1.0.0` should get out-of-date warning when running `npm outdated`.

How can I configure my `sample`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subcommand in npm called `deprecate`.

You can use the subcommand like this `npm deprecate <pkg>[@version] <message>`

To get more detailed explanation of the command and example , from the terminal run `npm help deprecate`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npm deprecate`. Basically you can run the following command:

```
npm deprecate library@"<2.0.0" "All versions older than v2.0.0 are deprecated."
```

Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/deprecate